# How to enter data into SQL Server using asp.net query string?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, querystringparameter

Guys I need to store data into a SQL Server database using a querysting. I want to store the data if someone changes URL and post that url back to server.

e.g.

```
www.example.com/Default.aspx?s1=123&s2=456
```

By pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> I want to store the value of `s1` and `s2` into SQL Server database.

How do I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to know this? The real problem will be detecting that it happened, going to be logs session auditing and a site map, or if possible serious interaction with the browser's address bar.

Comment: well the actual problem is that such url will be coming from the PIC32 platform. So once this URL post back I need to enter the data into SQL

Comment: That isn't what you asked. Storing which Url was used in a get or post is completely different to detecting whether some one manually typed in a different url in the browser address bar.If all you want is the former, should be able to set up logs and mine them.

Comment: can you guide me to any post describing how to do this? or provide me with the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Conn %>'InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [TableName] ([s1], [s2]) VALUES (@s1, @s2)" >
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="s1" Type="Int16"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="s2" Type="Int16"></asp:Parameter>
            </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
        // Redirect
    }
```